# How to parse a HTML page that is the POST request result (using curl, JSONPath, Xpath in PHP)?

Tags: php, json, curl, xpath, jsonpath

I need to parse this web page ....

http://monitorps.sardegnasalute.it/monitorps/MonitorServlet?page=carLavoroPresidi&tipoProntoSoccorso=TUTTI&codiceAziendaSanitaria=200102&idPresidio=102MAD02&indirizzo=null&idProntoSoccorso=30

... using PHP to extract the numbers that are in the table under le columns "ROSSO", GIALLO", "VERDE" and "BIANCO".

[image]

*(NOTE: you could see different value in that page if you try to browse it ... it doesn't matter ..,, it change dinamically .... )*

Those values are a POST request result inside the web page.

This is the PHP code that I'm using to send a POST request using curl, and than parse the JSON response (using Skyscanner JSON Path .. it's working fine in my code .. ),  trying to extract the values using a XPath parsing.

```
<?php
    include "./tmp/vendor/autoload.php";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "http://monitorps.sardegnasalute.it/monitorps/MonitorServlet",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "idMacroArea=null&codiceAziendaSanitaria=200102&idAreaVasta=null&idPresidio=102MAD02&idProntoSoccorso=30&tipoProntoSoccorso=TUTTI&vicini=null&xhr=true",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      ),
    ));

    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);

    $jsonObject = new JsonPath\JsonObject($server_output);

    $jsonPathExpr = '$..view';

    $res = $jsonObject->get($jsonPathExpr);
    print $res[0];

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML(json_encode($res[0]));

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $xpath_for_parsing = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]';

    $colorWaitingNumber = $xpath->query($xpath_for_parsing);
    $theValue =  'N.D.';
    foreach( $colorWaitingNumber as $node )
    {
      $theValue = $node->nodeValue;
    }

    print $theValue;

    ?>
```

The result is in the following image

[image]

where the table is the result of the command in my code ...

```
print $res[0];
```

and

**N.D**

is the result when I try to parse to extract one of my desired value

About the xpath that I'm using I've checked it verifying with the page source code ......

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved!

My original code was "quite" right except for a mistake.

You've to comment this line ...

```
//@$dom->loadHTML(json_encode($res[0]));
```

and substitute it with this one

```
@$dom->loadHTML($res[0]);
```

and all will work fine!